# JetBrains Rider and T4MVC templates referencing EnvDTE

Tags: t4, jetbrains-ide, rider

I have a reference to Host (`IServiceProvider`) in one of my T4MVC templates. Of coarse all is well when running this in Studio but I am wondering if anyone has solved this issue for Rider.

There are references to `EnvDTE` & `EnvDTE80` which do not seem to exist when executing the template with Rider. My guess is that they are just leveraging the TextTransform utility which does not appear to have access to the `IServiceProvider` implementation.

I would love to solve this and make the move entirely to Rider. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have several related issues: [RIDER-5245](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-5245) [RIDER-9415](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-9415) [RIDER-5687](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-5687)

Briefly: we can not work with such templates because we use command line utility texttransform.exe. 
We have plans to implement our own implementation. Later.